# Binding number keys in tmux

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to bind `C-1` in tmux? When I try it I receive an error:

`unknown key: C-1`

Here's what I'm trying:

`bind-key -n C-1 select-window -t 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type Ctrl-V Ctrl-1 at a shell prompt, you won't get any output (compare to Ctrl-V Ctrl-i, for example).

Running `xev`, Ctrl-1 gives "1" with a state code signifying that Ctrl is held down, so you may be able to map Ctrl-1 to an unused escape sequence using `xmodmap` and then map that sequence to the `select-window` function in `tmux`.

Comment: If you map ctrl-1, a common combination, in xmodmap, won't that affect all programs? e.g., ctrl-1 in Chromium / Chrome will no longer jump to the first tab.

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski: True, but I'm not aware of another way to accomplish what the OP asked without affecting other things.